# puppeteer, Is it possible not to close the browser after exiting the node process?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Please tell me, is it possible not to close the browser after exit nodejs process and connect to it?
In Selenium, this is possible using chromedriver

```
   const connectedBrowser = await puppeteer.connect({
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
      browserWSEndpoint
    })
```

Comment: The option name is `detached`. Somewhere in the documentation or the puppeteer source code you can find it. If you launch the browser with `spawn`, the same `detached` option applies.

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to do this as a crutch through spawn. I thought there were more civilized variants :)